# Where did this squirrel come from?

Tags: trials-evolution

In Trials Evolution, I noticed on the stats screen that I have apparently collected a squirrel:

[image: Squirrels Collected?]

I was a bit surprised by this because I don't remember seeing any squirrels in the game (apart from the one on the loading screen). **How do you collect squirrels? How do you know once you've collected one?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The squirrels in Trials Evolution are 'items' hidden throughout the game. You have to navigate to them, or in some cases wait until after a trial has been completed. I don't know of any benefit that you get to collecting all of the squirrels aside from that personal sense of satisfaction.

http://www.trueachievements.com/a163721/the-squirrels-have-eyes-achievement.htm

The link above goes into greater detail about where to find the squirrels and even includes several videos of finding all the squirrels.

Answer (score 2):

Full video guide to the Squirrel achievement.

Part 1: 1-9

Part 2: 10-16

Part 3: 17-20 (Click the link in part 2s video description. )

-Rambo